# Free-to-use server where my webapp can temporarily store images and make them available via URL

Tags: gratis, images, api, hosted

I want to save images temporarily and I want to send the picture's url address to a different service in my react application. Which api can I use for free? I can not use imgur because it is closed in Turkey.

Comment: Must it be gratis? Or what is your budget?

Comment: I have no budget. I just want to save these picture one or two minute. Can i make this?